# How to control content in columns in html5

Tags: html, css, browser

I am writing some code for a webpage and I want it to be in two separate columns. Within the columns div tags there are who separate div blocks, and I want each block of code to be in a different column. However, when the website is displayed in the browser everything after Inside the Kitchen appears in the second column. How do I fix this?

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="columns">
    <div>
        <h2>Cupcake of the Week</h2>
        <p>This week's featured cupcake is the Avacado Chocolate cupcake. Its strange combo of   flavours will kick your taste buds into fiesta mode!</p>
        <img src="images/featured-cupcake.jpg">
        <h2>Inside the Kitchen</h2>
        <p>
            Smells Like Bakin’ started out in the garage of the husband wife duo Allison & Joseph. Allison is the baker, and Joseph found a way for them to make a 
            business out of her tasty treats. Flash forward to today and they have a successful store front, catering business and cupcake truck.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Fresh Out the Oven</h2>
        <p>Our newest cupcakes are Bacon Me Crazy and Jalapeno So Spicy.</p>
        <img src="images/new-cupcake-bacon.jpg"> <img src="images/new-cupcake-jalapenojpg">
        <h2>Get Bakin' with Us</h2>
        <p>Call us: 1-555-CUP-CAKE<br>Email us: bakeon@smellslikebakin.com</p>
        <p>We announce all of our new flavors first through Facebook & Twitter, and even take requests!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#columns {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. Works fine for me! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfhgx/)

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct:

http://jsfiddle.net/NqGhu/

Probably on css you set style in other attribute, in `h2` or `p` for example